# 400 bad request when trying to submit a POST request

Tags: http, http-post, httpwebrequest

I'm applying to a job and the way they ask their applicants to send in a resume is through api. The directions ask:

Submit a POST request to our careers endpoint with a raw JSON request body:

Here is the json:

```
POST https://contact.website.com/jobs


{
  "name": "Jane Applicant",
  "email": "jane@hotmail.com",
  "resume": "www.linktoresume.io",
  "github": "github.com/jane", 
  "twitter": "@jane", 
  "website": "jane.com" 
}
```

I used postman and chose post as the request then put in the correct url. I created keys and values for all of the fields they expected but I get a 404 bad request when I try to submit. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you've set the POST request format to JSON:

[image]

Comment: Also make sure that you don't need any credentials to POST

Comment: It's giving me back an error saying "must provide resume" I did do that but I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Do I need to use a .io link?

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately as I don't know what the endpoint is expecting I can't really help, do they have any documentation describing what they're expecting to receive?

Comment: Just whatever I've posted above in my question

Answer (score 0):

Comments aren't allowed in JSON so the body should just be

```
{
  "name": "Jane Applicant",
  "email": "jane@hotmail.com",
  "resume": "www.linktoresume.io",
  "github": "github.com/jane",
  "twitter": "@jane",
  "website": "jane.com"
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I didn't add comments